# Google App Engine upload project

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have to upload a Python project online and i'm using Google App Engine Launcher.
Using the login and password of my account on Google (the account that I used for Developers console), appear this message"Error Failed; auth error.".
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate an app specific password here:
https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords

Alternatively, you can use OAuth2 to upload your program.
See for more info:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2